# Find Button Code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, class, button

I am trying to see the code associated to a button in eclipse, but without success..

How can i see all the code associated to the button?

see also [find class associated by button id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595090/find-class-associated-by-button-id)

Comment: any button.. I want to see the code associated to them..

Comment: @João Duarte : Are you talking about Swing buttons???????????

Comment: Indeed! what kind of button?? I thougth at first It was about the IDE, which I found a  nice question,   but the code for 'any button' is a none-question.  I create HTML-buttons too in eclipse for example

Comment: is not the code of the button.. i already have the button code.. but i want to see the classes that have the button programmed.. I am programing to android.. In netbeans i can see all the references or actions of an determinated button.. I want to see that in eclipse.. Sorry about my english;)

Comment: @joão Duarte :  I deleted my answer since it was not an answer on your question

Comment: @joão Duarte: try my answer. @peter may be call hierarchy and find option is what he need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Double click on button variable.
2. Press `ctrl + alt + h` [Open call hierarchy]. This will calling hierarchy of that button variable.
3. Or simply go to `Search --> File Serach`. And search for variable in project.

And to see declaration press `F3` or `ctrl + click` on variable name.

Also on Search menu on top has many other options to find reference in workspace or project.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt-Shift-F2 and click on the button you are interested in. This will open the "Plug-in Menu Spy", and display a pop-up with something like this (when clicking on the "Debug" toolbar button):

```
The active contribution item identifier:
    org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.DebugDropDownAction
The active contribution location URI:
    toolbar:org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet?after=org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.DebugDropDownAction
The active action set identifier:
    org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet
```

Now you know that the contributed action is `DebugDropDownAction`, which (if you have the proper sources) you can open using "Open Type" (Ctrl-Shift-T).

(There is also a "Plug-in Selection Spy" bound to Alt-Shift-F1 which will display similar information about the current selection.)