# find class associated by button id

Tags: android, eclipse, class, button, reference

) I want to see all references of the button id in all the class's of an android project..

How can i do it? using something like find? iam using eclipse..

Comment: By the way : this question reminds me of another one.. ;-) Much better put and tagged (android!) here.

Comment: By the way 2  : you should upvote and accept some answers, that way people might do an effort for you in the future.  You might read the FAQ here SO (stackoverflow) is a very friendly and powerfull community, you will benefit from it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the object in Code, than

Press **control** **shift** **g**

which is  the project shortcut for this path

> Menu > Search > References >
>   Project... (or workplace, ..)

Comment: Nice!! In that case we normally upvote the answer (we do that with all answers that are usefull) and maybe accept it (only one answer)

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your button and Eclipse will generate error's on all the references to that button :-)

Of course you can also 
**search with Crtl+F**
Or by 
**Menu -> Search -> References**

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Search -> Search`

Select `File Search` Tab

Enter your search text.

```
and Enter File Name Patter as *
```